# Nuget dependency error installing RavenDb Embedded

Tags: dependencies, nuget, ravendb, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to install RavenDB.Embedded in an ASP.NET MVC 5 application, but I have this dependency error:

```
PM> Install-Package RavenDB.Embedded
Attempting to resolve dependency 'RavenDB.Database (= 2.5.2750)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Spatial (≥ 5.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'WindowsAzure.Storage (≥ 2.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager (≥ 1.7.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.OData (≥ 5.0.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.Edm (= 5.0.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Spatial (= 5.0.2)'.
Install-Package : Updating 'System.Spatial 5.2.0' to 'System.Spatial 5.0.2' failed. Unable to find a version of 'RavenDB.Database' that is compatible with 'System.Spatial 5.0.2'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package RavenDB.Embedded
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Have I any other options than to install it manually?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is caused by [NuGet 2.8's new features](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.8).  Do this instead:

```
Install-Package RavenDB.Embedded -DependencyVersion Highest
```

Comment: The project is new and it was the first package that I try to install. I have updated all the base packages but it doesn't work. For information, I am working with .net 4.5 and not 4.5.1 but I don't know if it's make a difference0

Comment: Updating to latest gives me v 5.6.0 of odata, edm and spatial.  Which all still work.  Whatever is holding you back to 5.0.2 is the issue.  I don't think it's raven.

Comment: I have tried with a new MVC project, updated all the things I can (in Nuget and Visual Studio Extensions), and I have cleared the Nuget Package Cache but I still have the same error. I don't know chat to install/update in order to fix that. I used VS2013 Update 1. Do I need to remove some other references first?

Comment: Looks like I hadn't got the latest NuGet.exe update.  After updating to latest (2.8) I am seeing the same thing as you.  Others on the RavenDB list are reporting it also, and the solution appears to be to downgrade NuGet to 2.7.  Not sure what the root cause is yet. I'm still investigating.

Comment: Thanks for your amazing investigating work! :)
I will try it as soon as I can.