# Nuget package RavenDB.Embedded: Unable to find a version of 'RavenDB.Database' that is compatible with 'System.Spatial 5.0.2'

Tags: nuget, ravendb, nuget-package

In a new project when I try to add the NugetPackage : RavenDB.Embedded
I have the following error :Updating 'System.Spatial 5.2.0' to 'System.Spatial 5.0.2' failed. Unable to find a version of 'RavenDB.Database' that is compatible with 'System.Spatial 5.0.2'.

Comment: Problem solved : it's a VS 2012 problem. With VS 2013 it works fine.

Comment: Ran into the same issue, VS 2013 had no impact.  It looks like it's trying to bring down System.Spatial 5.0.2 event though the package says it needs 5.2.0.  Not sure what's up with that...perhaps there is an issue with the package.

Comment: I had to add it manually with -IgnoreDependencies

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nuget dependency error installing RavenDb Embedded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515178/nuget-dependency-error-installing-ravendb-embedded)

Answer (score 20):

i think this is a nuget bug. try using:

```
Install-Package RavenDB.Embedded -DependencyVersion Highest
```

Comment: It's not really a bug in NuGet. By default NuGet will install the lowest compatible package rather than what most people seem to expect the highest. I believe the reason is that the view is that the older packages are more stable and more likely to work as expected.